# Hacer una alerta en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo que realizar un formulario en el que ingresemos nuestro nombre y apellido y al darle a un botón nos muestre una alerta en el navegador diciéndonos hola + nuestro nombre + nuestro apellido el código es el siguiente. El problema que me da es que al darle al botón de saludar no me realiza ninguna acción no muestra alertas y aparentemente no hace nada:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ejercicio 1</title>
    <script src="js/site.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formulario">
        <label id="lblNombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input id="Nombre" type="text"/>
        <br />
        <label id="lblApellido">Apellido:</label>
        <input id="Apellido" type="text"/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="button" name="btnSaludar" value="Saludo" id="btnSaludar" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

y a continuación el JavaScript:

```
window.onload = inicializarEventos;

class Persona{
    constructor(nombre, apellido){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
}

function inicializarEventos() {
    var miBoton = document.getElementById("btnSaludar");
    miBoton.addEventListener("click", saludar(), false)
}

function saludar() {
    var nombre = document.getElementById("Nombre").value
    var apellido = document.getElementById("Apellido").value
    var persona = new Persona(nombre, apellido);
    var saludo = "Hola: " + persona.nombre + " " + persona.apellido
    alert(saludo)
}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar es mi primera pregunta en esta plataforma muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando tu mandas una función como callback, necesitas mandar el nombre de la función, pues si tú mandas el nombre más (), lo que haces es llamar la función; no referenciarla. Tu error está en esta linea

```js
miBoton.addEventListener("click", saludar(), false)
```

Al mandarle saludar() como segundo parámetro no mandas la referencia; ejecutas la función, tu código debería de verse así

```js
miBoton.addEventListener("click", saludar, false)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,  aparte de eso me di cuenta de que tenía mal la ruta del archivo al script. Es mi primer día aprendiendo javascript y ya veo que es muy diferente de java 